# How to fix the Javascript "anonymous function"

Tags: javascript, requirejs, reveal.js

I want to design some slides by Javascript, and use the Reveal library and follow the template 
https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/index.html

and plan to embed a charts into the slides by echarts library and follow this demo
http://ecomfe.github.io/echarts/doc/start-en.html

I put these two library as follow directory without any change of echarts/reveal library.

```
|--echarts-2.2.0
|--reveal.js
\--mySlides.html
```

When I merged these two demo together, I got the "anonymous function" of "require.config". No idea how to debug it. Anyone can help it? Thanks.

Uncaught ReferenceError: Reveal is not defined
  (anonymous function)  mySlides.html:36

mySlides.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>reveal.js - The HTML Presentation Framework</title>

    <meta name="description" content="A framework for easily creating beautiful presentations using HTML">
    <meta name="author" content="Hakim El Hattab">

    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reveal.js/css/reveal.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reveal.js/css/theme/black.css" id="theme">

    <!-- Code syntax highlighting -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reveal.js/lib/css/zenburn.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="reveal">

    <!-- Any section element inside of this container is displayed as a slide -->
    <div class="slides">

            <section id="page1" data-background="#ff0000">
                    <div id="main" style="height:400px"></div>
                    <!-- ECharts单文件引入 -->
                    <script src="echarts-2.2.0/build/dist/echarts.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        require.config({
                            paths: {
                                echarts: 'echarts-2.2.0/build/dist'
                            }
                        });

                        // 使用
                        require(
                                [
                                    'echarts',
                                    'echarts/chart/bar'
                                ],
                                function (ec) {
                                    var myChart = ec.init(document.getElementById('main'));

                                    var option = {
                                        tooltip: {
                                            show: true
                                        },
                                        legend: {
                                            data:['销量']
                                        },
                                        xAxis : [
                                            {
                                                type : 'category',
                                                data : ["衬衫","羊毛衫","雪纺衫","裤子","高跟鞋","袜子"]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        yAxis : [
                                            {
                                                type : 'value'
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        series : [
                                            {
                                                "name":"销量",
                                                "type":"bar",
                                                "data":[5, 20, 40, 10, 10, 20]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    };
                                    myChart.setOption(option);
                                }
                        );
                    </script>
            </section>
            <section id="page2"><p>Page2</p></section>
    </div>

</div>

<script src="reveal.js/lib/js/head.min.js"></script>
<script src="reveal.js/js/reveal.js"></script>

<script>

    // Full list of configuration options available at:
    // https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration
    Reveal.initialize({
        controls: true,
        progress: true,
        history: true,
        center: true,

        transition: 'slide', // none/fade/slide/convex/concave/zoom

        // Optional reveal.js plugins
        dependencies: [
            { src: 'reveal.js/lib/js/classList.js', condition: function() { return !document.body.classList; } },
            { src: 'reveal.js/plugin/markdown/marked.js', condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( '[data-markdown]' ); } },
            { src: 'reveal.js/plugin/markdown/markdown.js', condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( '[data-markdown]' ); } },
            { src: 'reveal.js/plugin/highlight/highlight.js', async: true, condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( 'pre code' ); }, callback: function() { hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); } },
            { src: 'reveal.js/plugin/zoom-js/zoom.js', async: true },
            { src: 'reveal.js/plugin/notes/notes.js', async: true }
        ]
    });

</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the requirejs file loader. Put this in the header of your file and let me know if that fixes it.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.16/require.js"></script>
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Reveal is not defined
  (anonymous function) mySlides.html:37
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () {
   root.Reveal = factory();
   return root.Reveal;
  }
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
  makeError require.js:166
  intakeDefines require.js:1236
  (anonymous function) require.js:1423

Comment: After looking at your code a bit closer, there are a number of other things that look problematic as well. Why are you including so many files using script tags if you're using requirejs? For example the echartsjs file is included on line 31 and then required again on line 42. Also, if 'dist' is the folder that echarts is in, why are you telling requirejs that it's a javascript file? I've never used either of these libraries so I may not be a lot of help, but I would first read up on requirejs and then build your page incrementally.

Comment: Maybe start with a page using strictly reveal and once that is working properly try to add the charts library so you don't end up with a small novel in your error log.